# What does "turn the coffee on" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In a small English training video, there is a sentence "Would you turn the coffee on": https://youtu.be/bRb4D1lmr4M?t=24

Since I can't see anything related with coffee in the screen, I can't understand it. Does it mean turn on the coffee machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [turn on](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-on_1) usually means make something start working. In the video, the voice asks the lights and music be turned on.

Strictly speaking, music is not something that can be turned on. You turn on musical devices such as MP3 player to start music. However, it is idiomatically expressed that way.

To turn the coffee on also means to turn a coffee maker (machine) on.